# How to get the selected option from ui-select multiple

Tags: ui-select

I have some issues figuring out how to get the selected value in a multi select form from `ui-select`. 
I have made a snippet to show you what I want to do. In my html I have a made an ui-select with an ng-change-event callback: `ng-change="onDatasetChanged(whatShouldBehere?)"`. When the option is selected, I want to print the selected model only inside the `onDatasetChanged()`-method in my controller.

```js
angular.module('myApp',['ui.select']).controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
  
  $scope.myUiSelect={model:{}}; // encapsulate your model inside an object.
  $scope.availableData=["a","b","c"]; //some random options
  
  $scope.onDatasetChanged = function(selectedValue){
    console.log("selectedValue",selectedValue);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-select/master/dist/select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-select/master/dist/select.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  
  
  
  <ui-select multiple ng-model="myUiSelect.model" close-on-select="false" title="Choose a dataset" ng-change="onDatasetChanged(whatShouldBehere?)">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select something">{{$item.label}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="data in availableData | filter:$select.search">
                        {{data}}
      </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
  
  
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit of research on the repository page for the [`ui-select`-directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select)
I figured you could use an `on-select` event binding like this:
`on-select="onSelect($item, $model)"`. See the updated snippet:

```js
angular.module('myApp',['ui.select']).controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
  
  $scope.myUiSelect={model:{}}; // encapsulate your model inside an object.
  $scope.availableData=["a","b","c"]; //some random options
  
  $scope.onSelect = function(item,model){
    console.log("selectedItem",item);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-select/master/dist/select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-select/master/dist/select.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  
  
  
  <ui-select multiple ng-model="myUiSelect.model" close-on-select="false" title="Choose a dataset" on-select="onSelect($item, $model)">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select something">{{$item.label}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="data in availableData | filter:$select.search">
                        {{data}}
      </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
  
  
  
</body>
```